# Peru e-Invoicing XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

i'm struggling with creation of the C# class from the XSD files, which are provided on the [website of the government](https://s3.amazonaws.com/insc/ComprobantesDePago+Electronicos/eFacturas+d+sistemas+contrib/Act23dic2014/XSD_FE23122014.zip).

I'm using XSD.exe console application to generate C# class. But still no success...

Only error message:

*Error: Error generating classes for schema '_\UBLPE-Invoice-1_0'.
  - The element 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2:UBLExtensions' is missing.*

Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: It is telling you that the source xsd is malformed. It is missing an element.

Comment: Yes, i know... i checked that document and it seems to be there. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i solved by myself. Problem is that xsd.exe file is not supporting IMPORT in XSD, so it is necessary to insert command for creation in following way:

```
xsd.exe main.xsd imported_xsd.xsd imported_xsd_2.xsd ... imported_xsd_n.xsd
```

After that i was able to produce class without any problem.